# Android : How to sync countdown timer on recyclerview item and dialog?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, countdowntimer

I have a recycler view with countdown timer on it's item. When I click on it, I want to show dialog and countdowntimer on it same as clicked item.

Example:
Two textview is on recyclerview.
One with timer 3:00:00
Second with timer 1:00:00

Now, when i click first item. Dialog should open with count down timer with it. 
the timer on dialog should sync and show 3:00:00. 
When timer on clicked item decrease to 2:59:59, same should happen on dialog.

I tried,

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderholder holder, final int position) {
startTimer(holder.timerTextView,pos);

  holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                isItemClicked =true;
                pos = position;
                clickOnRecycleItemsInterface.clickRecycleItem(position);
                saveEventTimeLeftToSession(clickedEvent);
            //show dialog here
            }
        });
}

public void startTimer(final textViewTimer, final int position){
//timer code here which perfectly changes time on textViewTimer
new CountDownTimer(totalMilSec,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
      //How can I update timer on dialog from here?
       //I tried storing time on static variable here and fetch from dialog
       // but that didnot worked

      }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add listener from dialog to recyclerview  and update the corresponding item and call notifydataSetChanged().

Comment: Can you give example code please. If I have 3 items in recyclerview, i only want timer from clicked item to sync with timer on dialog. Thanks,